# If {$x$}' is closed then {$x$}' is the union of disjoint closed sets.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I'm reading about separation axioms weaker than $T_1$ on topological spaces.
One article makes the following claim:

In an arbitrary topological space $(X,\tau)$ (Not necessarily $T_1$)

"If for all $x\in X$ it satisfies {$x$}' is a closed set then for all $x\in X$ it satisfies {$x$}' is the union of disjoint closed sets."

Could you please give me some observation by which is true?

Remark: {$x$}' means the derived set of the point $x$.

Comment: I don't get the claim here. Clearly $\{x\}'$ is the union of... itself? That's trivially true. Is that the correct statement?

Comment: Yes, the statement is "If for all $x\in X$
 it satisfies {$x$}' is a closed set THEN for all $x\in X$ it satisfies {$x$}' is the union of disjoint closed sets. Can I write {$x$}'$=${$x$}'$\cup \emptyset \dots$?

Comment: Sure. Or you can simply write $\{x\}'=\{x\}'$. Or more precisely if $C=\{\{x\}'\}$, then $\{x\}'=\bigcup C$. Because union of a single set is perfectly valid and well defined. Note that in general you cannot expect $\{x\}'$ to be a disjoint union of more than one set.